# Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case "1":') to another

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I am trying to display total price on simple C# console program. But Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case "1":') to another errors occur. What is my mistake?

```
    using System;
    class a
    {
        static void Main()
        {

        start: Console.WriteLine("1. Cofee 2. Jam. 3. Bread 4. Apple");
            String a = Console.ReadLine();

            int price = 0;
            switch (a)
            {
                case "1": price += 2;
                case "2": price += 3;
                case "3": price += 4;
                case "4": price += 5;
                    Console.WriteLine("your selected item is {0} Your price is ${1} Do You Want to Continue? YES or NO", a, price);
                    String max = Console.ReadLine();
                    max = max.ToUpper();

                    if (max == "YES")
                    {

                        goto start;

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        break;
                    }


                default: goto start;

            }

        }



    }
```

Comment: You really need to re-think how you have structured this program. Using "goto" is not idiomatic C# and this is NOT a habit you want to form or your code will become a maintenance nightmare. Think about using a loop structure like 'while' to achieve this behaviour instead.

Answer (score 4):

I understand your program is a loop and you select an item in each iteration. The price of this item should be added to the total. But the problem is all the prices are added each time.

You need to use `break;` to stop execution of `switch`:

```
switch (a)
{
    case "1": price += 2; break;
    case "2": price += 3; break;
    case "3": price += 4; break;
    case "4": price += 5; break;
}
```

Remove the rest of the code from `switch` then.

You can find more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx):

> Execution of the statement list in the selected switch section begins with the first statement and proceeds through the statement list, typically until a jump statement, such as a **break**, goto case, return, or throw, is reached. At that point, control is transferred outside the switch statement or to another case label.

Comment: The OP wants to fall-through i.e. execute the matching case statement and those below

Comment: @W.K.S I'm pretty sure he doesn't. That looks very unlikely.

Comment: Really? Isn't that what he meant by `Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case "1":') to another`

Comment: @W.K.S I think he doesn't want fall-through. Looking at the code, it's a loop (with goto!) and you select an item in each iteration. The price of this item should be added to the total. But the problem is all the prices are added each time.

Comment: I agree. Looks like he ASSUMES it will not fall through. THe code otherwise makes zero sense. Clarly that is an issue of his understanding of .NET.

Answer (score 4):

You need to insert a `break;` statement between each `case`.

Also, it looks like you want that code to display your message if the selected choice is 1 - 4. You can rework your logic a bit to accomplish that, removing the need for a `goto`:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1. Cofee 2. Jam. 3. Bread 4. Apple");
    String a = Console.ReadLine();

    int price = 0;
    switch (a)
    {
        case "1": price += 2; break;
        case "2": price += 3; break;
        case "3": price += 4; break;
        case "4": price += 5; break;
        default: continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("your selected item is {0} Your price is ${1} Do You Want to Continue? YES or NO", a, price);
    String max = Console.ReadLine();
    max = max.ToUpper();

    if (max == "NO")
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
            case "1": price += 2;
                      goto case "2";
            case "2": price += 3;
                      goto case "3";
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to fall through cases is a restriction in the C# language specification.  What you're doing wrong is trying to fall through.

Comment: More exact: A restriction in the langauge design - and documented in the language. The compiler just follows the language specifications.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect that it's a restriction in the C# language spec.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get fallthrough like behavior you need to explicity state that you mean to fall through. This is done using goto. ex:

```
switch (a)
{
    case "1": price += 2; goto case "2";
    case "2": price += 3; break;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your switch block should probably look like this (note the `break;` statements):

```
switch (a)
{
    case "1":
        price += 2;
        break;
    case "2":
        price += 3;
        break;
    case "3":
        price += 4;
        break;
    case "4":
        price += 5;
        break;
    default: goto start;
}
```

It also looks like you want this section of code to run *after* the switch, not just if they selected Apple.

```
Console.WriteLine("your selected item is {0} Your price is ${1} Do You Want to Continue? YES or NO", a, price);
String max = Console.ReadLine();
max = max.ToUpper();

if (max == "YES")
{
    goto start;
}
else
{
    break;
}
```

---

You will probably need to reorganize your entire program. I think this is what you want to do:

```
using System;
class a
{
    static void Main()
    {

    start: Console.WriteLine("1. Cofee 2. Jam. 3. Bread 4. Apple");
        String a = Console.ReadLine();

        int price = 0;
        switch (a)
        {
            case "1":
                price += 2;
                break;
            case "2":
                price += 3;
                break;
            case "3":
                price += 4;
                break;
            case "4":
                price += 5;
                break;
            default: goto start;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("your selected item is {0} Your price is ${1} Do You Want to Continue? YES or NO", a, price);
        String max = Console.ReadLine();
        max = max.ToUpper();

        if (max == "YES")
        {
            goto start;
        }
    }
}
```